# What are the description of the following Japanese company leaves? (交通遮断休暇、予防休暇)

Tags: words

I tried to look for the description of these Japanese company leave but I can't find any internet site that gives a direct description. (交通遮断休暇, 予防休暇)

I found the meaning of the following words in my electronic dictionary:

- 交通 = traffic
- 遮断 = cut-off, shut out
- 予防 = prevention

From these, I derived the equivalent English terms as:

- 交通遮断休暇 = Road Blockage Leave
- 予防休暇 = Preventive Leave

However, I still can't grasp the meaning by just the definition alone. Can you please give me a description of these company leaves?

Or are these leaves a unique term, created by a specific company, and not used by all companies?

Answer (score 2):

交通遮断休暇 would refer to a situation where one is unable to report to work due to a public transport strike. I imagine this is quite unheard of in Japan as it rarely happens.

I can't offer much explanation for 予防休暇 except that it may be related to a (possibly self-imposed) abstention from reporting to work to prevent the spread of infection to the workplace, such as in cases of influenza.

Comment: Depending on the workplace type (e.g. a school), the second one might refer to a shutdown when a certain percentage of people are sick.